# Tiered memberships

Tags: add-on, members, bestpractice, accounts

I'm currently in the speccing stages of a site and considering ExpressionEngine as an option.

One of the requirements is for "tiered memberships" for instance:

A user signs up as a member with a "Corporate" account
This "Corporate" account can have a number of sub-accounts, say for employees.

Has anyone created a system like this within EE before? Is there any kind of add-on that will do this or is it a matter of working with an add-on that shifts members into channels and creating related entries etc.

I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If yes, please mark the answer correct by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No direct experience doing this, but I'd take this approach initially:

- Each "tier" is a channel entry. You could include things like price, description, etc. here (perhaps this is also a "products" channel used by [CartThrob](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cartthrob-2) or [Store](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/expresso-store), used to "sell" the tier).
- Use an add-on such as [Zoo Visitor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-visitor) or [Profile:Edit](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/profileedit) to create members as channel entries, then use a relationship or [Playa](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/playa) field in that entry which links them to a specific tier (I like Playa better for this, as its various :parents, :children, :siblings tags are very powerful).

Comment: You would also, however, have to add relationships from a Corporate member to their sub-member accounts, and if you needed permissions to be based on that it could get complicated quickly. (Like if all users in a given corporation needed to be able to edit the entries of the corporation.)

Comment: Yes that would be a requirement. Although I can argue a case for not doing that - with the corporate account just there to add sub-accounts as it were.

With that said I'm starting to get an idea of how I can accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't done this myself, but did need a sort of multiple "groups" or member "tagging" kind of feature. The easiest way it seems to do this in EE is to expose Channel Categories as a Member field or something similar. There are two commercial add-ons I know of that do this:

[IntoEEtive's Member Categories](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/member-categories)

and

[Addon Bakery's Member Categories](http://www.addonbakery.com/docs/member-categories.html).

I chose to go with the latter (don't remember why anymore, though). Note that when it displays Categories as a custom Member Field in the Edit Profile page it does not display them the way you arrange them in the Control Panel. It's simply a select or multi-select. Perhaps that could be a feature request. (jQuery Chosen plugin is no longer used as per the documentation screenshots either, you'd have to enable that manually.)

As for relationships between specific members and sub-categories... I don't know. Probably would require custom development?